# I am trying to scrape amazon, and stop at a specific number

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, increment

So this is my code

```js
if (body.included != null && body.included.length > 0) {
    let genres = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < body.included.length; i++) {
        genres += body.included[i].attributes.title;
        if(i != body.included.length - 1) {genres += ', ';}
    }

    embed.addField('GENRES', [`${genres}`,], true);
}
```

this is the results whenever i search anything with this it gives me this:

```
Comedy, Kids, Fantasy, Fantasy World, Erotic Torture, Loli, Nudity, Bdsm, Bondage, Sex, Past, Plot Continuity, Violence, Military, Mecha, Historical, Action, Romance, Science Fiction, World War II, Japan, Asia, Piloted Robot, Alternative Past, Steampunk, Gunfights, Alien, War, Robot, Adventure, Space Travel, Cyborg, Crime, Other Planet, Humanoid Alien, Future, Space, Contemporary Fantasy, Vampire, Slice of Life, Detective, Bounty Hunter, Magic, Present, Demon, Super Power, Drama, Anime Influenced, Earth, Love Polygon, Angst, High School, School Life
```

Has this a example because other types searches comes with 1 or 2 or decent amount of genres where it doesn't have like 40 of them

like this one

```
Ninja, Fantasy World, Adventure, Action, Comedy, Martial Arts, Super Power, Romance, Disaster, Shounen, Love Polygon, Angst, Plot Continuity, Parallel Universe, Fantasy
```

So what i need help is how do i make it stop in a certain number where it wont give me 40 of them instead 10 or less

Comment: Have you tried changing your for loop condition?:  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the loop condition but still need to watch out for the length of the `body.included` array for cases where it has fewer than 10 elements. Try the following:

```
const MAX_GENRES = 10;
if (body.included && body.included.length) {
  const max = Math.min(MAX_GENRES, body.included.length);
  const genres = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < max) {
    genres.push(body.included[i].attributes.title);
    i += 1;
  }
  embed.addField('GENRES', [genres.join(',')], true);
}
```

This should achieve what you're after. I don't know the signature for `embed.addField()` but are you certain that the second argument should be a single-element array containing a string? Could be but seems weird. If the function calls for an array of strings use:

```
embed.addField('GENRES', genres, true);
```